# How to convert UTC to CEST, for my CSV file, in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm working on a project, where we are supposed to read a csv file, convert the datetime from UTC to CEST on the column and then send some of the columns to a MySQL database.

We are working on an ubuntu server, running MySQL and python 2.7.15+. The csv file is saved in the same folder as our python program. We can print the csv file, and remove a part of a string on the column `created_at`. We're having a hard time on converting the datetime from UTC to CEST.

We don't need a finished code, but a tip on how to get on the right direction is more than enough.

```
import pandas  

df = pandas.read_csv('feeds.csv')

df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].str.replace('UTC', '')

print(df)
```

The output will print the csv file, where a string on a column has been modified, so that it doesn't have UTC in it. It looks like the following:

`"2019-08-01 08:30:13 UTC"` is changed to `"2019-08-01 08:30:13"`

CSV file looks like this:

[image: d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below  [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html)

```
df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks! Been looking at that, but we're receiving this error: "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Will upload my csv file in my description

Comment: @Yas convert 1st in date time then apply convert method

Comment: Thanks, no error now. Seems like it works, but shouldn't it automatically update the time, so 12:50:13 changes to 14:50:13??

Comment: have you assigned it?